# SAS_ data repeat read

Tags: arrays, sas

I have raw data like this

```
time   ID01  ID02 ID03 ~ IDxx
0       10    11   xx
0.5     20    12   xx
1       29    25   xx
1.5     41    30   xx
2       50    40   xx
3       30    50   xx
4       40    42   xx
.       .     .
.       .     .
.       .     .
```

I want to make it to this form

```
x   time    temp.    
01  0       10       
01  0.5     20        
01  1       29       
01  1.5     41       
01  2       50       
01  3       30       
01  4       40       
02  0       11   
02  0.5     12    
02  1       25   
02  1.5     30   
02  2       40   
02  3       50   
02  4       42
```

I used array statement and proc transpose

but I can't repeat time variable beside temp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works using arrays. Just write an `output` within the loop and time will be written in your output datatset, and then sort.

```
data output;
    set input;
    array ID(*) ID01-ID03;
    do i=1 to 3;
        X=put(i,z2.);
        temp=ID(i);
        output;
    end;
    keep time X temp;
run;
proc sort data=output;
    by X time;
run;
```